# Iterating through multiple pages when web scraping pagination with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I'm trying to extract specific data from a webpage that typically contains multiple pages. Although I was able to print all of the information I needed on the first page, I couldn't do the same for other pages. I searched the internet for solutions and discovered that the majority of them looped through each page by concatenating a link page with a number.

However, I'm working on a website where the link page does not change when you navigate to different pages. Therefore, it's difficult for me to figure out which attribute causes the URL to redirect to the second page as there are no clickable links displayed.

When I inspect the look-alike next button, I get the following:

```
<div class="pagination__PageNavItem-s1515b5x-2 clogRN"><span class="pagination__PageNavigation-s1515b5x-3 cKpakR">→</span></div>
```

I was able to get the information I needed for the first page here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/arrivals/LHR/?year=2021&month=7&date=3&hour=12?page=12323213' 
html_page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')

airline_text = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "table__Cell-s1x7nv9w-13 iZEpOT"})

for n, i in enumerate(airline_text, start=1):
    print(n, '->', i.get_text())
```

Is there a way to iterate through the remaining pages?

Comment: which information you would like to parse ?

Comment: Airlines’ names

Comment: check my below answer then.

Comment: That's perfect! Can you elaborate on what you used to extract the airline names?

Thank you very much!

Comment: description included

Comment: I got it man, I appreciate that again!

Comment: if that's helped you out, Kindly check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `script` tag which contain the desired information, I've parsed it using regex where there's property called `name` contain the airline name.

```py
import requests
import re
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    params = {
        "year": "2021",
        "month": "7",
        "date": "3",
        "hour": "12"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    match = re.findall(r'"name":"(.*?)"', r.text)
    pp(match)


main('https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/arrivals/LHR/')
```

Output:

```
['London Heathrow Airport',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'JAL',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Emirates',
 'Qantas',
 'British Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Iberia',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Royal Jordanian',
 'Finnair',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'SWISS',
 'Air Canada',
 'United Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'ANA',
 'Aegean Airlines',
 'United Airlines',
 'American Airlines',
 'Finnair',
 'Iberia',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'United Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Lufthansa',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'Air Canada',
 'British Airways',
 'Etihad Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Iberia',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Gulf Air',
 'Fiji Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'Finnair',
 'Alaska Airlines',
 'Royal Jordanian',
 'EL AL',
 'Royal Jordanian',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Iberia',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Xiamen Airlines',
 'Iberia',
 'British Airways',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Iberia',
 'JAL',
 'JAL',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'United Airlines',
 'ANA',
 'Iberia',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Royal Jordanian',
 'American Airlines',
 'Finnair',
 'SWISS',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Finnair',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'Iberia',
 'Kuwait Airways',
 'Xiamen Airlines',
 'Garuda Indonesia',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'China Airlines',
 'KLM',
 'Gol',
 'Virgin Atlantic',
 'Delta Air Lines',
 'American Airlines',
 'Cathay Pacific',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'JAL',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Finnair',
 'Pakistan International Airlines',
 'United Airlines',
 'Air Canada',
 'EgyptAir',
 'TAP Air Portugal',
 'British Airways',
 'TAROM',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Delta Air Lines',
 'Iberia',
 'Air France',
 'British Airways',
 'Aeromexico',
 'KLM',
 'Virgin Atlantic',
 'Singapore Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'JAL',
 'American Airlines',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Lufthansa',
 'American Airlines',
 'United Airlines',
 'Croatia Airlines',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'JAL',
 'Iberia',
 'Finnair',
 'Aegean Airlines',
 'Cathay Pacific',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Finnair',
 'British Airways',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'American Airlines',
 'Cathay Pacific',
 'Emirates',
 'Saudia',
 'American Airlines',
 'Cathay Pacific',
 'LATAM Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Cathay Pacific',
 'Iberia',
 'Gulf Air',
 'British Airways',
 'Finnair',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Royal Jordanian',
 'Royal Jordanian',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'American Airlines',
 'Singapore Airlines',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'TAP Air Portugal',
 'Aegean Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'Azores Airlines',
 'TAP Air Portugal',
 'TAP Air Portugal',
 'Singapore Airlines',
 'Air New Zealand',
 'Air Canada',
 'Virgin Atlantic',
 'SAS',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'JAL',
 'Croatia Airlines',
 'Royal Air Maroc',
 'Finnair',
 'British Airways',
 'LATAM Airlines',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Finnair',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'Iberia',
 'Iberia',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'Air Canada',
 'British Airways',
 'United Airlines',
 'Aeroflot',
 'AZAL Azerbaijan Airlines',
 'Etihad Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'Turkish Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Qantas',
 'JAL',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Delta Air Lines',
 'Alitalia',
 'British Airways',
 'LATAM Airlines',
 'KLM',
 'Garuda Indonesia',
 'Virgin Atlantic',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'Qantas',
 'Malaysia Airlines',
 'Gol',
 'JAL',
 'Iberia',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'China Southern Airlines',
 'Xiamen Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Delta Air Lines',
 'Alitalia',
 'Kenya Airways',
 'Delta Air Lines',
 'Virgin Atlantic',
 'American Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'Biman Bangladesh Airlines',
 'ANA',
 'Kenya Airways',
 'Air France',
 'Aeromexico',
 'Gol',
 'Virgin Atlantic',
 'British Airways',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'British Airways',
 'Royal Air Maroc',
 'British Airways',
 'Iberia',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'SriLankan Airlines',
 'JAL',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Finnair',
 'Iberia',
 'British Airways',
 'JAL',
 'LATAM Airlines',
 'British Airways',
 'American Airlines',
 'Qatar Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'JAL',
 'British Airways',
 'JAL',
 'American Airlines',
 'SWISS',
 'Etihad Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'British Airways',
 'Aer Lingus',
 'Saudia',
 'Ethiopian Airlines',
 'TAP Air Portugal',
 'Singapore Airlines',
 'United Airlines',
 'Azores Airlines',
 'ANA',
 'EgyptAir',
 'EL AL',
 'Etihad Airways',
 'Korean Air',
 'Royal Air Maroc',
 'London Heathrow Airport']
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored inside the page in `<script>` tag. You can use next example how to extract it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/arrivals/LHR/?year=2021&month=7&date=3&hour=12?page=12323213"
html_page = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"__NEXT_DATA__ = (.*)", html_page).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for f in data["props"]["initialState"]["flightTracker"]["route"]["flights"]:
    print(
        "{:<8} {:<8} {:<3} {:<5}".format(
            f["departureTime"]["time24"],
            f["arrivalTime"]["time24"],
            f["carrier"]["fs"],
            f["carrier"]["flightNumber"],
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
07:10    12:10    QR  8866 
10:45    12:15    BA  827  
10:45    12:15    AA  6472 
10:45    12:15    EI  8327 
10:45    12:15    QR  5952 
11:00    12:20    BA  579  
11:00    12:20    AA  6838 
11:00    12:20    JL  7156 

...
```